# Fraternal Polyandry in Mahabharata,The Reasoning?

Tags: mahabharata

*Draupadi Vivah* in Mahabharata can be cited as an example of *fraternal polyandry* in ancient Indian social custom, which still exists in some parts of India (ref. 'Himalayan Polyandry'by D.N.Majumdar,Asia Publishing House London,1963).

But Mahabharata presents it as a stray event and provides few reasons for happening  of this kind of marriage. What are those ?